# Correct usage of os.path and os.join

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a handler that acts on files within various subdirectories, but while my script can *see* these files, it cannot do anything with them because it fails to assemble their paths.

The problematic part comes from this loop:

```
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk("data/"):
    for image in files: 
        #do something to the image
```

Now, the script works in the first level of the `data` directory, but fails to work on `data`'s subdirectories.

I tried using `os.path.join()`:

```
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk("data/"):
    print os.path.join(path, dirs)
```

But that throws the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bench.py", line 26, in <module>
    print os.path.join(path, dirs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 75, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

In short, what I'd like to do is assemble a path from `data` to the image which includes `data`'s subdirectories. What's the best practice for doing this?

Comment: When you get an exception like this, it's often because you're trying to do something to a list of values like `dirs`, instead of to each value. (If you didn't realize `dirs` is a list, the exception should raise that possibility as a red flag, and you can try `print dirs` or `print type(dirs)` to find out.) You can solve this by using a `for` loop, a list comprehension, `map`, etc., as mgilson's answer shows, once you recognize that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you want to join `path` with `file` for each `file` in `files`

```
for path,dirs,files in os.walk('data/'):
    for f in files:
        fname = os.path.join(path,f)
        assert(os.path.exists(fname))
```

`dirs` is a `list` of directories which are in the directory `path`.  You can actually modify `dirs` in place to prevent `os.walk` from walking into into certain directories (neat!).

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- Yes.  That's correct.  Thanks for the clarification.  (I edited -- Hopefully to avoid any confusion)

Comment: +1. And of course you can also `join` `path` with each `dir` in `dirs`, if you need to do something with the subdirectories (besides just see their names or prune the list).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk("data/"):
  for image in files: 
    fname = os.path.join(path, image)
    file = open(fname, 'rb')
```

The two examples at the [os.walk documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) both do just this thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk("data/"):
  for image in files: 
    file_path = os.path.join(path, image)
    # do your stuff
```